# Is there a way to access the GeoServer admin page remotely?

Tags: geoserver

I am running an instance of GeoServer on a linux server and I am trying to access the admin page on a separate machine. Is there a way for me to change the address so that I can access it through a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, find the jetty.xml and search for localhost. Change localhost to your IP address of the server. Then change the firewall settings to allow port 8080, I followed these [instructions](http://www.tixati.com/optimize/open-ports-linux.html)

Comment: I opened `jetty.xml` file, there was no any word `localhost`. Can you explain bit?